# Django ORM выбор связаных моделей

Tags: python, django

У меня есть 2 модели

```
class menu(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    menu = models.ForeignKey(menu)
```

Как при выборке связать их? Например что бы было так

```
m = menu.objects.all()
for i in m.item: #?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К связанным моделям тут можно обратиться как `m_instance.item_set`. Или задать (вместо стандартного *lowercased_classname*`_set`) название в `item` (кстати, в Python традиционно принято именовать классы с прописной буквы) через аргумент `related_name` в `ForeignKey()`.

Т.е. будет что-то в духе:

```
for m in Menu.objects.all():
    for i in m.item_set.all():
        ...
```

В документации все есть с примерами: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects (модели, используемые в примерах, описаны в самом верху страницы)

Здесь одно большое «но» — при этом для каждого объекта в `m` будет выполнен запрос `SELECT` из таблицы с `item`'ами. Если записей `menu` много, то запросов будет, соответственно, тоже много. В этом случае, возможно, имеет смысл как-то переделать структуру и, например, как-то выбирать `item`'ы и их `menu` через [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#select-related). В SQL это будет сформировано в духе `SELECT ... FROM items AS i LEFT JOIN menus AS m ON m.item_id = i.id ...`. А дальше в питоновом коде уже, возможно, перестраивать структуру, в зависимости от задач.

Answer (score 3):

Насчет ForeignKey я точно не уверен, для ManyToManyField есть [вот такое](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/#many-to-many-relationships).
Могу посоветовать поковырять [доки](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/), но что-то мне подсказывает, что нужно будет делать дополнительную выборку из базы, т.е.:

```
m = menu.objects.all()
for i in m:
    new_items = item.objects.filter(menu = i.id)
```

PS. Названия моделей должны быть с большой буквы - правила хорошего тона.

Comment: Черт, пока печатал ответ - уже ответили до меня)